# what is the difference between 'under construction' and 'renovation'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I saw some sentences.
This was written as 'His Web site is still under construction.'

I think it means 'repair process of existing web site' so I chose answer 'He has an online portfolio in his website' answer.

I now understand that it is so abstract that was not correct answer.
But I want to know what is the difference between 'under construction' and 'renovation'.

Does it depend on the context?

Comment: I can't have enough proofs to post an answer but they are almost the same.  Frankly I never hear or read "Renovation" but "Under construction" is when you are "building" something new or modifying something (making an overhaul?) and "renovation" I would say that it's more used when you are changing or improving something old.

Comment: The sentence "He has an online portfolio in his website" has no relation to either "under construction" or "renovation". When you say _"so I chose answer"_, what do you mean? Is this from an exam or study exercise?

Comment: @P.E.Dant yes it's on the TOEIC task book. i saw many sententces, for example, 'the road is under construcrion' i think that means same 'renovation'

Comment: @Ender Look hmm.. i think that 'the road currently is under construction' meaning same thing 'renovation'. don't it?

Comment: "He has an online portfolio in his website" is not the correct answer in that case. "His Web site is still under construction" means "He has not yet completed his website". "Renovation" does not mean "repair". Its actual meaning is closer to "make new again".

Comment: @P.E.Dant Oh..! I'm perfectly understood. thanks! :) 
The key is _'still'_ right?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean here. What answer does the key tell you is correct?

Comment: @SeanSin, yes...  But I would say that "your road" can be renovating **or** building a complete one when you day "under construction". But well, I am not an English native so I don't know exactly that.

Comment: @EnderLook The verb _renovate_ has the Latin adjective _novus_ as its root. _Novus_ means _new_, and _renovate_ means _to make new again._ Thus, its use should denote construction that it is not original, but a modification of some previous construction. "Under construction", though, could mean _either_ new construction or renovation of previous construction.

Answer (score 1):

**under construction** almost always implies something is being built for the first time.  It has become a commonplace phrase regarding web sites.

**renovation** always refers to major repair or overhaul of something that already exists.

One can renovate a site.  In that case it is being refreshed, not undergoing its initial establishment.

Both terms traditionally referred to building things like houses, bridges, or roads.  They pretty much maintain their traditional meaning when applied to web sites.

Comment: I'd argue that "under construction" is general enough to use in either case. *We're renovating our kitchen; it's been under construction since February.*

Comment: @cjl750 So "The website is still under construction" is meaning "The website is newly building" and "The website is currently redesigning" is meaning "renovate" right?

Comment: @SeanSin, yeah I'd say so.

Comment: @cjl750 In fact, the term **["under renovation"](https://www.google.com/search?q=website+under+renovation&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlhuPC2O7UAhVj0YMKHVVlAvkQ_AUICigB&biw=1262&bih=1300)** is often applied to websites.

Comment: @Catija I agree. That is why I said "almost always" in the first paragraph and contrasted it with "always" in the second. The denotation of "under construction" is quite broad. However, lacking contextual clues to the contrary, its connotation is that of initial establishment. Even your example sentence provided such a contextual clue, so I think we are in agreement.

Comment: @cjl750 The matter does not warrant a prolonged colloquy, but a **[general search](https://www.google.com/search?biw=320&bih=460&ei=iuFbWeKPFcPCjwS12KSADA&q=website+renovation+home+page)** also shows that _renovate_ is certainly applicable (and often applied) to websites. This is apposite to your surmise about the applicability of the term here. The image search I presented demonstrates the same thing, and anyone who is in the design business often hears the phrase "renovate our website". I know because I was.

Comment: @P.E.Dant The better phrasing would have been "not *as* applicable." I thought the rest of the comment made my meaning clear enough, but apparently not. I obviously can't edit the comment now, so I've deleted it. I'm not going to sit here and argue.

Comment: @cjl750 There is a profound distinction between _colloquy_ and _**[argument](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lvcnx6-0GhA)**_.